# Power Series with non integer exponent

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, exponentiation, formal-power-series

I will use the following definitions:
(I apologize in advance, my Latex skills are subpar)

$$\binom{\lambda}{n} = \frac{(\lambda).(\lambda -1)...(\lambda-n+1)}{n!}$$
and $$\binom{\lambda}{0} = 1$$
With $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

$$(1+X)^{(\lambda)} :=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\lambda}{n}\cdot X^n  $$

The exercise is as follows;

Prove the following,

$$(1+X)^{\lambda}(1+X)^{\gamma}=(1+X)^{\lambda + \gamma}$$

I attempted to use induction on the nth term of the power series resulting of the product, however I was unable to prove it. Is there a more algebraic aprroach or identity that could crack this problem?

Comment: In Latex, if you want an equation in an exponent you use a^{x+y} with curly braces rather than parentheticals, you can look at my edit to see :)
A power series with non integer exponents sound like a Puiseux  Series..?

Comment: This power series looks like it does have integer exponents—perhaps it's the binomial coefficients whose top entries are not integers?

Comment: Your definitions are really weird. Is that intentional or a typo? Binomial coefficients normally have $n!$ in the denominator, not just $n$. 

Should your second equation be for $n=0$?  Should your power series start at $n=0$?

Comment: You’re going to need a generalization of Vandermonde’s identity to show this directly - not sure how to do that though. I think you normally prove that using this identity which you can show using Taylor series. I suppose you can show it’s a polynomial expression true for all integers and therefore (something something finite polynomials have finite roots) is true as a polynomial.

Comment: @AnikPatel Thank You!

Comment: @Eric Yes, sorry about that, I've just corrected it

Comment: With a bit of power series theory the result follows easily - the power series converge near zero, satisfy a linear degree 1 ODE which matches for the product and initial condition same so they are equal (product and the $\gamma + \delta$ one); then the formal stuff follows since power series equal over the complex numbers (or real numbers) means coefficients equal

Answer (score 0):

There is a purely algebraic way to show this with formal series, the conditions i needed to prove it were these :

Supposing $\mathbb A$ is a commutative ring that contains $\mathbb Q$ (by that I mean a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$, because if there is one then it is unique and the isomorphism is unique as well) then the structure is enough to define binomial coefficients :
$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb A, \, \forall n \in \mathbb Z, \, \binom{\alpha}{n} := \left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (\alpha-i)}{n!} & \text{ if } n \geq 0 \\
&0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
Then we have Vandermonde's identity (the one you're trying to prove)
$$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb A, \; \forall n \in \mathbb N, \; \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{\alpha}{i} \binom{\beta}{n-i} = \binom{\alpha+\beta}{n}$$

Proof :

We'll be using
$$\exp := \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{1}{n!} X^n$$
$$U := \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} X^n \text{ (basically }\ln(1+X)\text{)}$$
$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb A, \; (1+X)^\alpha := \exp \circ (\alpha U)$$

First, we show that with this new definition of $(1+X)^\alpha$, we have
$$(1+X)^0 = 1$$
$$(1+X)^1 = 1+X$$
$$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb A, \; (1+X)^\alpha (1+X)^\beta = (1+X)^{\alpha+\beta}$$
So our new notation doesn't conflict with integer powers of $1+X$

Second, we show that the definition I've given to $(1+X)^\alpha$ matches with the other definition, that uses binomial coefficients :
\begin{align*}
\forall \alpha \in \mathbb A, \; ((1+X)^\alpha)' &= \alpha U' \cdot \exp' \circ (\alpha U) \\
&= \alpha (1+X)^{-1} (1+X)^\alpha \\
&= \alpha (1+X)^{\alpha-1}
\end{align*}
We get the $n$-th derivative by induction :
$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb A, \; \forall n \in \mathbb N, \; ((1+X)^\alpha)^{(n)} = \left(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha - i \right) (1+X)^{\alpha-n}$$
and the coefficients of $(1+X)^\alpha$ :
\begin{align*}
\forall n \in \mathbb N, \; [X^n](1+X)^\alpha &= \frac{1}{n!}[X^0]((1+X)^\alpha)^{(n)} \\
&= \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (\alpha - i)}{n!} [X^0] (1+X)^{\alpha-n} \\
&= \binom{\alpha}{n} [X^0] \exp \\
&= \binom{\alpha}{n}
\end{align*}
and the identity
$$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb A, \; (1+X)^\alpha (1+X)^\beta = (1+X)^{\alpha+\beta}$$
yields
$$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb A, \; \forall n \in \mathbb N, \; \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{\alpha}{i} \binom{\beta}{n-i} = \binom{\alpha+\beta}{n}$$